# Show that $\frac{f'(x_0)}{f(x_0)}=-\frac{g'(x_0)}{g(x_0)}$ for some $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The problem is as follows:

> Let $f(x),\ g(x)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose that $f(b)=g(a)=0$ and $f(x),g(x)\neq 0,\forall x\in (a,b)$. Show that there exists $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that
> $$\frac{f'(x_0)}{f(x_0)}=-\frac{g'(x_0)}{g(x_0)}$$

---

I know that with the generalized mean value theorem, we can find that

$$\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$$
$$\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}=\frac{0-f(a)}{g(b)-0}$$
$$\frac{f'(x_0)}{f(a)}=-\frac{g'(x_0)}{g(b)}$$
which is close, but not quite right. However, I cannot think of any other theorem that would be able to relate $f'$ and $g'$ at the same point. The only way I can think of to continue from the above is to multiply on
$$\frac{f'(x_0)}{f(a)}\frac{f(a)}{f(x_0)}\frac{g(b)}{g(x_0)}=-\frac{g'(x_0)}{g(b)}\frac{f(a)}{f(x_0)}\frac{g(b)}{g(x_0)}$$
but that just kicks the can down to needing to somehow argue that $\frac{g(b)}{g(x_0)}=\frac{f(a)}{f(x_0)}$, values we know nothing about.

Comment: Thank you, that is enough for me to get it. Rearranging it like that just did not occur to me.

Comment: No problem! I deleted my comment since I was going to add an answer, but you figured it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Consider the function $F(x)=g(x)f(x)$.

Then $F(a)=F(b)=0$ so by MVT there is an $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $F'(x_0)$ is $0$.
As $F'(x)=g(x)f'(x)+g'(x)f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ [and in particular $F'(x_0)=0$ $=g(x_0)f'(x_0)+g'(x_0)f(x_0)$] and $f(x_0),g(x_0)$ are both nonzero, what does this imply.

Answer (score 1):

You may recognise the expressions in the target equality as logarithmic derivatives. It is possible to base a split on that observation:

Negating $f$ and/or $g$ changes nothing, hence we max assume that $f,g$ are positive over $(a,b)$ and define $u(x)=\ln f(x)$, $v(x)=\ln g(x)$. Now the problem becomes:

> Let $u,v$ be diff‘able on $(a,b)$, both bounded from above, $u(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to b$, $v(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to a$.
> Then show that $u‘(x_0)=-v’(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in (a,b)$.

The claim is equivalent to $(u+v)‘(x_0)=0$. And this follows from $(u+v)(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to a$ as well $x\to b$ so that we readily find $a<a‘<b‘<b$ with $(u+v)(a‘)=(u+v)(b‘)$ and then can apply Rolle.